# Why the bytecodes for the same smart contract in testnet explorer and Remix/solcjs are different?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, remix, rsk

I am using [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org/) to compile and deploy my smart contract to Rinkeby and [RSK](https://explorer.testnet.rsk.co/) test networks.
I don't understand why the bytecode of my contract on [Rinkeby explorer](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/) is different from the `metadata.data.deployedBytecode.object` in Remix artifacts and also different from `evm.deployedBytecode.object` coming from [solcjs](https://github.com/ethereum/solc-js) compiler. I also tried this on RSK and I got the same issue.

That's what I do in Remix:

I create a `MegaHonk.sol` file in `contracts` folder

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity 0.8.7;

contract MegaHonk {
  uint256 public count;

  event LoudSound(address indexed source);

  function honk() external {
    require(tx.origin != msg.sender, 'EOA not allowed');
    count += 1;
    emit LoudSound(tx.origin);
  }
}
```

I select the appropriate compiler version `0.8.7`, select Environment: `Injected provider - Metamask`, compile and deploy to Rinkeby. The contract successfully deploys. Then I go to Rinkeby explorer, find [my contract bytecode](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x960D46D7e29997AdF49587686DEEf027b6fC4591#code) and compare it with the one in `remix-file-explorer/contracts/artifacts/MegaHonk.js` in the `metadata.data.deployedBytecode.object` property.

**Bytecode from Rinkeby is 1348 symbols long** and
**Bytecode from Remix is 1350 symbols long**.

The exact same thing happens when I am compiling the same smart contract with `solcjs` compiler. I use the right version `0.8.7` and these input parameters:

```js
const input = {
  language: 'Solidity',
  settings: {
    outputSelection: {
      '*': {
        '*': ['evm.deployedBytecode', 'evm.bytecode'],
      },
    },
    optimizer: {
      enabled: false,
    },
  },
  sources: {
    'MegaHonk.sol': {
      content: MegaHonk,
    },
  },
};
```

Why does this happen? What compiler parameters should I use to make the bytecodes identical in the Remix artifacts, solcjs compiler and in blockchain explorer (Ethereum or RSK testnets)?